# Unhandled exception: Access violation reading location 0x015E2348

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, loops

Ok I have a little problem with my code. This error disp when I try run it.

> Unhandled exception at 0x012D4CBF in Dywan.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x015E2348.

When ROZMIAR=257 or less then code works properly. But i need set higher value like 500. Error stucked at `double odcien = dane[x][y] + dane[x + dlboku][y] + dane[x][y + dlboku] + dane[x + dlboku][y + dlboku];`
Should i use dynamic arrays to this ?

```
double dane[ROZMIAR][ROZMIAR];
double wartoscinit = 0.0;
dane[0][0] = dane[0][ROZMIAR - 1] = dane[ROZMIAR - 1][0] = dane[ROZMIAR -1][ROZMIAR - 1] = wartoscinit;`

void comp_Fractal(){
for (int dlboku = ROZMIAR - 1; dlboku >= 2; dlboku /= 2, h /= 2.0)  {
    int polboku = dlboku / 2;
    for (int x = 0; x<ROZMIAR - 1; x += dlboku) {
        for (int y = 0; y<ROZMIAR - 1; y += dlboku) {

            double odcien = dane[x][y] + dane[x + dlboku][y] + dane[x][y + dlboku] + dane[x + dlboku][y + dlboku];

            odcien /= 4.0;

            double wzor = (-h) + rand() * (2*h) / RAND_MAX;
            dane[x + polboku][y + polboku] = odcien + wzor;

        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x<ROZMIAR - 1; x += polboku) {
        for (int y = (x + polboku) % dlboku; y<ROZMIAR - 1; y += dlboku) {


            double odcien =
                dane[(x - polboku + ROZMIAR) % ROZMIAR][y] +
                dane[(x + polboku) % ROZMIAR][y] +
                dane[x][(y + polboku) % ROZMIAR] +
                dane[x][(y - polboku + ROZMIAR) % ROZMIAR];

            odcien /= 4.0;

            double wzor = (-h) + rand() * (2*h) / RAND_MAX;
            odcien = odcien + wzor;

            dane[x][y] = odcien;

            if (x == 0) dane[ROZMIAR - 1][y] = odcien;
            if (y == 0) dane[x][ROZMIAR - 1] = odcien;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i<ROZMIAR - 1; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j<ROZMIAR - 1; j++) {
        if (dane[i][j] > maxY)
            maxY = dane[i][j];
        if (dane[i][j] < minY)
            minY = dane[i][j];
    }
```

}

Comment: Most compilers put local variables on the stack, including arrays. On e.g. Windows the default process stack size is only a single megabyte, if you exceed that you will get a *stack overflow*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When both `dlboku`, `y` and `x` are something like `ROZMIAR - 2`, following

```
dane[x + dlboku][y + dlboku];
```

will make you to access `dane[ROZMIAR + ROZMIAR - 4][ROZMIAR + ROZMIAR - 4]` which is out of bounds. You alvays had a problem with your code. It just large values of `ROZMIAR` which made it access out of allocated memory and crash.